# Colspan of table layout not working

Tags: extjs

I am trying to get table layout work on a panel, the layout works fine until I introduce "colspan" to it.

In the api docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.layout.container.Table.html, 
there is a fiddle which runs fine untill I change the code to

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Table Layout',
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 3
    },
    defaults: {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle: 'padding:20px',
        style: 'border: 1px solid black'
    },
    items: [{
        html: 'Cell A content'
    },{
        html: 'Cell B content',
        colspan: 2
    },{
        html: 'Cell C content',
        colspan: 2
    },{
        html: 'Cell D content'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Notice that all the cells now have equal widths. 
Why is colspan not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, but not as you expected, because every cell takes as much space as required, and the columns are sized accordingly.

That way, the first column takes 50% of the width, because Cell A content requires as much space as Cell B content, the third column takes 50%, because Cell D content requires as much space as Cell C content, and the second column is reduced to 0%.

You can see that for yourself if you add below Cell D a row without colspan:

```
{
    html: 'Cell E content',
},{
    html: 'Cell F content'
},{
    html: 'Cell G content'
}
```

Then you see that colspan is working correctly.

Update: I just found how to fix it. It's not trivial to find...

First, you have to add width to the layout:

```
    columns: 3,
    tdAttrs:{
        width:100
    }
```

Second, you have to add widths to all cells:

```
    html: 'Cell A content',
    width:100
},{
    html: 'Cell B content',
    colspan: 2,
    width:200
...
```

Don't ask WHY it works, I just don't know, it's completely counter-intuitive.

Comment: This actually goes against my understanding, but I think you are right. Tried it out in a html table and I am getting the same results. Is there any other way I could achieve my goal using table layout, adding dummy panels would look odd.